# How to display a postgreSQL array in a matlab command window?

Tags: postgresql, matlab

I've created a table is postgres with a single column called sessionResults.
datasource = 'test';

```
conn = database(datasource,'username','password');


    

data = sqlread(conn, "sessions");
head(data, 8)

close(conn)
```

The information is being entered correctly, but when i try to display it in the matlab command window all I get is this:

> ```
>       sessionresults
> ```

```
_________________________________

{1×1 org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray}
{1×1 org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray}
{1×1 org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray}
{1×1 org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray}
{1×1 org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray}
{1×1 org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray}
{1×1 org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray}
{1×1 org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray}
```

I know that the correct info is being inserted as if I print the information in the SQL shell I get the right results, I just want to be able to display the retrieved array in the matlab command window.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to convert them to Matlab strings or similar; Java objects don't display nicely inside table arrays. Something like this:

```matlab
asString = repmat(string(missing), size(data.thatArray));
for i = 1:numel(asString)
  javaString = data.thatArray{i}.toString;
  asString(i) = string(javaString);
end
data.thatArrayAsString = asString;
```